# Embed SWF file in firefox add-on (no SDK)

Tags: firefox-addon

I have a problem with a firefox extension i'm developing.

I need to add an SWF file in the page. If I load it from a remote server, it works fine:

```
myObj2.setAttribute("data",'http://www.mySite.com/myFile.swf');
myPar1.setAttribute("value",'http://www.mySite.com/myFile.swf');
```

It works fine but is not accepted for the review.

so I created a resource dir in the manifest:

```
resource   ldvswf   swf/
```

and changed the script into:

```
myObj2.setAttribute("data",'resource://ldvswf/myFile.swf');
myPar1.setAttribute("value",'resource://ldvswf/myFile.swf');
```

but it doesn't work. The folder resource://ldvswf is ok as i tested loading an image and I see it.

The reviewer wrote me that for flash file it "requires doing so via a file: URL", but I don't know how to manage, I tested:

```
'file: resource://ldvswf/myFile.swf'
'file://resource://ldvswf/myFile.swf'
'file://ldvswf/myFile.swf'
'file: ldvswf/myFile.swf'
```

And nothing works.

Any suggestion for the right path?

Thanks a lot!
Nadia

**Update: the editor wrote me:**

You need a file URL that points to an actual file. If your extension is unpacked, something like the following should do:

```
Services.io.newFileURI(Services.io.newURI("resource://ldvswf/myFile.swf", null, null)
                              .QueryInterface(Ci.nsIFileURL).file)
          .spec
```

But I don't understand how to plce it to replace:

```
myObj2.setAttribute("data",'http://www.mySite.com/myFile.swf');
myPar1.setAttribute("value",'http://www.mySite.com/myFile.swf');
```

I made some test like:

```
var file = Services.io.newFileURI(Services.io.newURI("resource://ldvswf/myFile.swf", null, null).QueryInterface(Ci.nsIFileURL).file).spec ;

myObj2.setAttribute("data",file);
myPar1.setAttribute("value",file);
```

But I get this error message:
*Error: NS_NOINTERFACE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004002 (NS_NOINTERFACE) [nsIFileURL.file]*

Comment: the var file = ... line works for me (after replacing the path to something i have)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `contentaccessible=yes` in your `chrome.manifest`, like this:

```
content  package_name   content/ contentaccessible=yes
```

I tested it with an image in a local web page and it worked, don't know for SWF:

```
<img src="chrome://package_name/skin/window.png"/>
```

Another approach is to get the file URI of the **chrome://** (not resource://) file like this:

```
function chromeToPath (aPath){
    if (!aPath || !(/^chrome:/.test(aPath))){
       return null; //not a chrome url
    }
    var Cc = Components.classes, Ci = Components.interfaces;
    var spec, url, file;
    var ios = Cc['@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1'].getService(Ci["nsIIOService"]);
    var uri = ios.newURI(aPath, "UTF-8", null);
    var crs = Cc['@mozilla.org/chrome/chrome-registry;1'].getService(Ci["nsIChromeRegistry"]);
    var fph = Cc["@mozilla.org/network/protocol;1?name=file"].createInstance(Ci.nsIFileProtocolHandler);
    spec = crs.convertChromeURL(uri).spec;
    return spec;
}
```

usage:

```
chromeToPath('chrome://package_name/skin/window.png')
```

and it will return the **file://** URI of the file.

If you test this, better make sure the extension is unpacked (unzipped) on install:
in `install.rdf`:
    <em:unpack>true</em:unpack>

Comment: Tested the "contentaccessible=yes". It is the same. On resource (or from contentaccessible folder) I can load an image without any problem, but not the swf

Comment: Did you try the other approach i suggested? I think it *should* work since it will be using a `file://` URI

Comment: I added an update to the question, with the editor indications, can you help me on that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try breaking the line like this:

```
var file = Services.io.newURI("resource://ldvswf/myFile.swf", null, null).QueryInterface(Ci.nsIFileURL).file;
alert(file.path)
var file = Services.io.newFileURI(file).spec ;
alert(file)
```

the first alert() should give a local system path like 'c:\folder\filename...'
the second should give a file:// URI

so what do you get?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've been away for a while. With your script I get no alert at all and in the error console I get: `Timestamp: 24/04/2014 12:13:18
Error: NS_NOINTERFACE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004002 (NS_NOINTERFACE) [nsIFileURL.file]
Source File: chrome://ldvgenerator/content/ldvgenerator.js
Line: 174`  Line 174 is the first of your script

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have a line in `package.json`:

```
   "unpack": true,
```

at the same level as name, title, author etc.  Note that `true` does not have the quotes.

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/package_json)